# Parallel Query execution is slowing down Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, parallel-processing

**Configs**:

```
Postgres version: `PostgreSQL 10.6`
Processor Name: Intel Core i7
Processor Speed:    2.2 GHz
Number of Processors:   1
Total Number of Cores:  4
L2 Cache (per Core):    256 KB
L3 Cache:   6 MB
Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
Memory: 16 GB
```

The same query is run on local and production with the same dump and Postgresql versions.
However in local it is using multiple workers and making the query slower.
What is happening here?
Why is it happening this way?
How to make local use single worker thus making it faster?

**Query on Local:**

```
explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "hogwarts" WHERE "hogwarts"."destroy_marker" = true AND ("hogwarts"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "mapped_hogwarts"."hogwart_id" FROM "mapped_hogwarts"));
```

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=123880322.67..123880322.68 rows=1 width=8)  
->  Gather  (cost=123880322.46..123880322.67 rows=2 width=8)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=123879322.46..123879322.47 rows=1 width=8)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on hogwarts  (cost=0.00..123879309.80 rows=5063 width=0)
                     Filter: (destroy_marker AND (NOT (SubPlan 1)))
                     SubPlan 1
                       ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..3467.60 rows=132040 width=4)
                             ->  Seq Scan on mapped_hogwarts  (cost=0.00..2291.40 rows=132040 width=4)
```

*Query on Production*

```
explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "hogwarts" WHERE "hogwarts"."destroy_marker" = true AND ("hogwarts"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "mapped_hogwarts"."hogwart_id" FROM "mapped_hogwarts"));
```

```
 Aggregate  (cost=10678.88..10678.88 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Seq Scan on hogwarts  (cost=1417.00..10673.74 rows=10288 width=0)
         Filter: (destroy_marker AND (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1)))
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Seq Scan on mapped_hogwarts  (cost=0.00..1353.86 rows=126285 width=4)
```

More info on the query like (analyze, buffers, verbose) that ran on local:

```
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=123880322.52..123880322.53 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=635589.193..635589.193 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   Buffers: shared hit=13004652 read=8396, temp read=2409553 written=226
   ->  Gather  (cost=123880322.31..123880322.52 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=635480.878..635590.731 rows=3 loops=1)
         Output: (PARTIAL count(*))
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=13004652 read=8396, temp read=2409553 written=226
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=123879322.31..123879322.32 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=635504.402..635504.402 rows=1 loops=3)
               Output: PARTIAL count(*)
               Buffers: shared hit=13004652 read=8396, temp read=2409553 written=226
               Worker 0: actual time=635451.409..635451.409 rows=1 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=6503547 read=2245
               Worker 1: actual time=635581.310..635581.310 rows=1 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=6500035 read=2360
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.hogwarts  (cost=0.00..123879309.80 rows=5002 width=0) (actual time=119.355..635491.922 rows=8017 loops=3)
                     Output: hogwarts.id, hogwarts.key, hogwarts.uuid, hogwarts.hogwart_data, hogwarts.destroy_marker, hogwarts.created_at, hogwarts.updated_at, hogwarts.content_title_text, hogwarts.source_type, hogwarts.source_id
                     Filter: (hogwarts.destroy_marker AND (NOT (SubPlan 1)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 44170
                     Buffers: shared hit=13004652 read=8396, temp read=2409553 written=226
                     Worker 0: actual time=105.015..635442.437 rows=6697 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared hit=6503547 read=2245
                     Worker 1: actual time=108.193..635571.569 rows=6693 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared hit=6500035 read=2360
                     SubPlan 1
                       ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..3467.60 rows=132040 width=4) (actual time=0.007..52.750 rows=132032 loops=24056)
                             Output: mapped_hogwarts.hogwart_id
                             Buffers: shared hit=13004451, temp read=2409553 written=226
                             Worker 0: actual time=0.008..69.863 rows=132035 loops=6698
                               Buffers: shared hit=6503494
                             Worker 1: actual time=0.008..69.807 rows=132023 loops=6695
                               Buffers: shared hit=6499986
                             ->  Seq Scan on public.mapped_hogwarts  (cost=0.00..2291.40 rows=132040 width=4) (actual time=0.007..38.505 rows=132029 loops=13394)
                                   Output: mapped_hogwarts.hogwart_id
                                   Buffers: shared hit=13004451
                                   Worker 0: actual time=0.007..38.535 rows=132035 loops=6698
                                     Buffers: shared hit=6503494
                                   Worker 1: actual time=0.007..38.474 rows=132023 loops=6695
                                     Buffers: shared hit=6499986
 Planning Time: 0.996 ms
 Execution Time: 635591.329 ms
```

https://github.com/suryapandian/weird/blob/master/db/hogwarts_json.json

Comment: Please show us the execution plans generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, verbose)` only then can we see the actual performance difference ([edit] your question, don't put additional information in comments)

Comment: Have added those in https://github.com/suryapandian/weird/blob/master/db/hogwarts_json.json

Comment: The JSON output format is intended for computers, not for humans. Please generate them using `explain (analyze, buffers, verbose, format text)`

Comment: Okay will get it in text format, but that query will take time. Will update in few minutes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name have updated the info you have asked for.

Comment: How do you know parallel execution makes it slower? What happens if you disable parallel execution on using `set set max_parallel_workers_per_gather=0;` and run the query? How fast is is then?

Comment: I removed the `postgresql-9.5` tag as parallel execution wasn't available in that version

Comment: The only difference that I am aware of between prod and local was the value of `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`. However it is weird and inconsistent, sometimes it is faster when `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` is set as 0. Sometimes even with 0 value the query takes so long. Not sure what is causing this.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated, but I wouldn't recommend using NOT IN here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN
Try `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM mapped_hogwarts WHERE mapped_hogwarts.hogwarts_id = hogwarts.id)`

Comment: What is the PostgreSQL version on both machines?

Comment: @Jeremy yes that is a good thing to do, did just that and that fixed this issue. But still wondering why it is faster of prod and slower on local when it is the same data.

Comment: @Surya On local it was using a hashed subplan and on production it was not.  Maybe there is a slight difference in the data or in the statistics between the two machines.